# Entity Framework: How to use FK relation instead of creating new table entries?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, key-value

I use EF to create an item database with technical/logistical details. Both have a key-value relationship: Key is a category and the value is the value in this category. Eg: Size - 3x3x3cm (Size = Category; 3x3x3cm = Value).

I want to use existing keys again, instead of creating duplicates and have code like the following to search for the key-object:

```
public int searchForKey(string key)
    {
        int result = 0;
        using (var db = new ItemModelContainer())
        {

            var keystable = from b in db.Keys where b.KeyText == key select b.Id;
            if (keystable.Count<int>() >= 1)
            {
                return result = keystable.First();
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }

        }

    }

    public Key getKeyOfDB(string key)
    {
        Key result;

        using (var db = new ItemModelContainer())
        {
            result = db.Keys.Find(searchForKey(key));
            return result;
        }

    }
```

By creating the Key-Value relationship (I use a class called "PropKV"), I use a constructor for existing keys:

```
public PropKV(string name, Key key, string val)
    {
        using (var db = new ItemModelContainer())
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Key = key;
            this.Val = new Val(val);
        }
    }
```

Even though the debugging shows me I am finding the correct key, I always get new entries in my key table and no reference to existing key-entries.

Why is this so? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new entity because you do so. The constructor of `PropKV` just assigns some values to the properties; you don't make any use of the `db` variable you instantiating in the `using` statement.
Since you want to load your entity from the DB, you can do this at the point where you instantiating your `PropKV` class, like this:

```
var propKV = db.ItemModelContainer.Find(key);
```

Of course you should embrace this in a `using` statement;

If you want to keep this code within your entity (and don't bother the consumer with EF) add a static method which returns the entity with a given key:

```
public static PropKV LoadFromDB(string Key)
{
    PropKV result = null;

    using (var db = new ItemModelContainer())
    {
        result = db.Find(key);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change anything. My PropKV has the following columns: Id;Name;ItemNumber;Key_id;Val_id (Key and Val id are FK - the PK of Key and Val are numeric: id). That's why I search for the id in the operation above. 

The LoadFromDB operation is nothing else than what my getKeyOfDB(...). 

When I integrate your solution to my code, it still gives me the same result: New Key entries...

Comment: Same result? You mean records are duplicated? This should be due to something else in your code. In the above lines we're just searching through existing records...